# How to understand current limiter circuit

Tags: mosfet, current-limiting, constant-current

[image: Current limiter]

Here the MOSFET IRF9530 works in linear mode of operation and transistor works in forward active.
Load resistance is 5 Ω and up to 15 Ω I can keep this MOSFET is linear mode and on increasing further it enters saturation region. I want to know the working of this circuit? And how a MOSFET can be operated in linear mode? Here transistor is used for biasing the MOSFET I think and how it is used?

Comment: Here the circuit starts limit current at about 200mV on shunt(not 600mV as standard limiter) because 400mV across BE is always presented from R2/R4 divider.

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried to simulate the circuit?

Answer (score 2):

Current to the load flows through R1 and M1. As load current increases, the voltage difference across R1 increases, which raises Q1's emitter voltage relative to the base (Veb rises), which "turns on" Q1 more, allowing more current to flow out of the collector. This raises the voltage at the gate of M1 (Ic • R5), making M1's Vgs less negative, which allows less current to flow through M1, counteracting the original increase in current.

The current setpoint can be changed by altering the ratio of R2/R4 (R2/R4 larger lowers the setpoint, R2/R4 smaller raises it).

Answer (score 1):

Working of circuit ... Made with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110).

[image]

Internal output impedance is rather high, something like 1.1 Ohm.